# Using dispatch method upload the data based on button action in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, upload, uibutton, grand-central-dispatch

I am new one of using Grand central dispatch. I read the Apple documents about using GCD but still I have no idea about use this method. My thought is I have three type of upload buttons in my view and I clicked the button simultaneously I want to upload  the data based on button action using NSURLCOnnection upload the content of data dispatch queue method.How can i do this. Pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading Mike Ash's blog on grand central dispatch - it will give you a good idea of how to use its APIs in your own code.  If his blog and Apple's docs are STILL not enough then I doubt that anyone on stackoverflow will be able to help you either since there's some conceptual hurdle that's not clear by your question.

The first three articles should help:

[GCD Intro part 1](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-28-intro-to-grand-central-dispatch-part-i-basics-and-dispatch-queues.html)
[GCD Intro part 2](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-04-intro-to-grand-central-dispatch-part-ii-multi-core-performance.html)
[GCD Intro part 3](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-11-intro-to-grand-central-dispatch-part-iii-dispatch-sources.html)