# What is the purpose of using Grand Central methods?

Tags: iphone, ios5, grand-central-dispatch

I want to use dispatch method in my application, but I don't really know anything about GCD. Can anyone explain how and why I should use CGD in my code?

Comment: Why do want to use "dispatch method" if you don't know want it does and why it is useful?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is GCD and where should it be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539656/what-exactly-is-gcd-and-where-should-it-be-used)

Comment: @Thilo upload the data to server I am sending data as queue

Comment: @Thilo Then only i want to use the dispatch method

Comment: Seems to be a flood of these "What is GCD and how do I use it?" questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488855/using-dispatch-method-upload-the-data-based-on-button-action-in-iphone  Maybe we should put together a meta-answer which sweeps all the beginners docs into one place?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably take a look at these tutorials. It is a step-by-step guide which breaks things down into a step by step guide explaining things fully every step of the process of downloading data asynchronously and updating in real time.

[iOS Multithreading With Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Basics](http://maniacdev.com/2011/07/tutorial-ios-multithreading-with-grand-central-dispatch-gcd-basics/)

Also have a look at the following:

[Grand Central Dispatch Objective-C Tutorial](http://www.mdube.com/technology/objective-c-tutorial-ios-4-features-grand-central-dispatch)

The above should get you started and make you understand what GCD is all about.